# Kendoui Datasource Switching

Tags: php, mysql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In an effort to reduce the number of requests on a particular page of mine, I would like to defer the loading of all the grids data to the server using PHP when the page is being requested.

I.e. Not to load the grid data in separate requests after the initial page load which is the common practice.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Which operations will you need to do with you Grid? Is all the data transferred at once or next pages will send requests? Will the Grid be editable?...

Comment: @OnaBai The most simple grid will not use pagination, but it will use filters and sorts. It will not be editable. I basically want the data set for the grid to be loaded with the rest of the page and not in a seperate ajax request (initially).

Answer (score 0):

You should have the the datasource created with an ajax call in order to keep your code clean, but if you really wanted to you could use php to write your js like this:

Inside your php file do an inline script:

```
<script>
var myDataSource = new kendo.data.Datasource({
  data: JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($myData); ?>)
});

$('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: myDataSource
});
<script>
```